# Downgrade an iPhone for testing purposes

Tags: ios, iphone, downgrade

I am wondering if it is possible to downgrade an iPhone to older versions of iOS even when the firmware is not signed by Apple.

I am a developer and I might need to install iOS6/7 on my iPhone, which currently has iOS8.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You can download simulator of iOS 6 ... Its easy way to test your app ...

Comment: I might need to test functionalities not available in the simulators (notifications, accelerometer.. etc. etc.)

Comment: Have a google, you can download the old IPSW files and install them through iTunes. - https://ipsw.me

Comment: try this may be help full ... I never try this .. http://www.wikihow.com/Downgrade-iOS

Comment: @Wezly how can i install them if Apple is not signing them anymore? that is my question

Comment: @Joge i will have a look on your link, but as far as i can read it's not possible to downgrade because of the signing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, if you had an older device and saved the SHSH blobs when Apple *were* still signing the firmware then you would be able to.

I keep an old device for each major version of the OS from 4 upwards, and you get get them on ebay for quite cheap. iOS 6 is a very small percentage of the overall market now, so unless you are needing to support it for a specific reason it would be best to drop support.

Comment: It's unbelievable that I am not able to choose the software that is installed on my iphone, there should be a way!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still interested in this in 2017, you can save your SHSH2 blobs by following [this guide](https://www.dailyifix.com/2017/05/how-to-save-ios-10-3-1-shsh-blobs/) & then using Prometheus from [Tihmstar](https://github.com/tihmstar/futurerestore).

Comment: Note: link-only answers are discouraged here!

Comment: Some people may want to go through official Apple channels.